# Firebase storage wont allow me to retreive image URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am successfully managing to upload files to the firebase storage.

However, when I include the .on function with statechanged, the console throws the following error:

> Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'testimonials.clientImg'

I am trying to retreive the image URL and place it in a variable.

My code is shown below, please can anyone assist?

```
  let itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('testimonials');
  let imgFile = this.state.currentImg;
  let imageRef;
  let imgURL;

  if (imgFile){
   imageRef = firebase.storage().ref("testimonialPics/"+imgFile.name).put(imgFile);


   imageRef.on('state_changed', (snapshot)=>{
    console.log(snapshot);
   })

  let clientObj = {
    name: this.state.currentName,
    feedback: this.state.currentComments,
    approved: false,
    clientImg: imgURL
  }

  itemsRef.push(clientObj);
  console.log(clientObj);

  this.setState({
    currentName: "",
    currentComments: "",
    currentImg: null
  })
```

Comment: None of the code. you shared calls `push()`, so it's very unlikely that the error comes from this code. Please double check the error message and stack trace, include them in your question, and ensure we have the code that throws the error.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I have no included the push method which seems to be triggering the error

Comment: You're not giving `imgURL` a value anywhere in this code, which would match with the fact that it's `undefined` when you call `itemsRef.push(clientObj)` and (as the error message says, you can't write an undefined value to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving `imgURL` a value anywhere in this code, which would match with the fact that it's `undefined` when you call `itemsRef.push(clientObj)` and (as the error message says, you can't write an undefined value to the database.

It looks like you're trying to write the download URL to the database. I'd following the [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example) closely for that. But based on your current code, it should be something like:

```
  let itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('testimonials');
  let imgFile = this.state.currentImg;
  let imageRef;
  let imgURL;

  if (imgFile){
   let ref = firebase.storage().ref("testimonialPics/"+imgFile.name); 
   let task = ref.put(imgFile);
   task.then(() => {
    // this runs when the upload has completed
    ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
      // this runs when the download URL has been determined
      let clientObj = {
        name: this.state.currentName,
        feedback: this.state.currentComments,
        approved: false,
        clientImg: downloadURL
      }

      itemsRef.push(clientObj);

      this.setState({
        currentName: "",
        currentComments: "",
        currentImg: null
      })
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url
Try this out. I think you are listening to the wrong listener.